# how to open a webview when ionic app launches?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I try to open a login page from desktop site with webview when my ionic app launches, but I failed.

Now I create a page which called login-check.page, and put a button in the page,  It will open the desktop login page with webview when user click it. This works fine.

But I want the webview automatically open when the app launches. Anyone can help? thank you in advance!

- `app.component.ts`

```js
export class MyApp {
    ...
    this.rootPage = LoginCheckPage;
}
```

- login-check.page.ts

```js
export class LoginCheckPage implements OnInit {
  ...

  ngOnInit() {
    /// this does not work
    // this.openWithWebview();
  }

  openWithWebview() {
    const targetUrl = this._api.getURL();
    const browser = this.InAppBrowser.create(targetUrl, '_blank', { location: 'no' });

    browser.on('loaderror').subscribe(event => {
      console.log("++++++" + event);
      browser.close();
    });
  }
}
```

- login-check.page.html

```html
<ion-content padding>
  <button (click)="openWithWebview()">Click</button>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you tried in this way in ngOnInit

```
const browser = this.iab.create('https://www.ionicframework.com','_self',{location:'no'});
```

Comment: Just tried, it works! thank you, why `this.openWithWebview();` in `ngOnInit` does not work? It just show a blank screen.

Comment: you are commented `this.openWithWebview();` in `ngOnInit` method. so that's why it is not working.

Comment: Because it does not work so I comment it :) when I change '_blank' to '_self', it works, I think it's related with whitelist url. thank you!